# how to remove Time from MVC5 DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I`m new to asp.Net mvc5. I have a problem with DateTime formatting. I need to remove time from Date.

```
20/01/2015 12:00:00
```

Needs to be like this :

```
20/01/2015
```

I Tried this :

```
var dateOnly = date1.Date;
```

But it still get the time with date.

Comment: Please show the code (or attribute) you're using to perform the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll always have some time in a `DateTime`object. But you can format the string output to have what you need. There is a difference between the inner data hold be the C# object (ie with time, even if 00:00) and the way you print it on screen.

Try:

```
var dateAsString = date1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Everything is in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format the date in a string, you can specify a custom format which excludes the time:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

By default, .NET will include the time too when converting a DateTime object to a string.